# Get the first and second character from string using PHP

Tags: php, string, str-replace

Please read this sentence..

```
Hello my name is ##John##
This is my ##question##
Thank you for ##reading## and giving your ##Answer##
```

See there are  many ## characters right?
Now What I want is to make the words inside the ## character **bold** which means to insert the words inside the HTML `<strong></strong>` tag, So what can I do to do this using PHP?
What I have tried is.....

```
$converted = str_replace('##', '<strong>', $toconvert);
```

But the problem is the second tag don't have closing / at the front, means all are  **tag only, and if sometimes the string have many ######## in it, then this will make problem too,**

This exactly what I want

```
 Hello my name is <strong>John</strong>
 This is my <strong>question</strong>
 Thank you for <strong>reading</strong> and giving your 
    <strong>Answer</strong>
```

So please help me to achieve this.

Thank you.

Edited

Keep in mind all the string is come from Database and it is stored in one variable not in array,
I just make it in new line to make it clear for you but I it is stored in PHP variable.

Thank you once again.

Comment: You are trying to process a non regular language using a tool only able to handle regular languages (speaking for the point of view of complexity theory). That means that there is no immediate, real solution for this. You'd have to use other, mightier tools for a real solution. Something like a language parser, maybe a "compiler compiler" to keep things simple. Take a look at `yakk` or `bison`.

Comment: There was a great answer and it did the job, the only thing is that if the text has many words and line brake happen the code will not working,

Comment: As for too many `###` in a row, I think I’d bail on those, that’s just invalid template code that an admin needs to solve. The alternative is to document that you do support it and define what it does. The search could be a simple `strpos`. The PHP parser doesn’t support `<?php<?php` for a good reason.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Okay forget about too many ##### just help me to make the other job please?

Comment: It seems like @Markus’s code would then work with just a slight adjustment? https://3v4l.org/5eoa6. There’s a comment about not allowing spaces but I’m not seeing that in the question so I’m not accounting for this. I’d write an answer, but I think Markus’s can just be reopened with a tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use regular expression for that

```php
preg_replace('/##(.*?)##/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $input_lines);
```

- `.*?` means lazy evaluation which do the magic (trying match as small as possible)
- you can test regex in some online tool like https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/G9K#tab-preg-replace

Comment: `preg_replace('/##([^#]+)##/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $data);` It works with this code which comes from @Chris Haas.   Thank you for both of you.